# Access 2010 Subform The data was added to the database but the data won't be displayed

Tags: ms-access-2010, subform

I have a strange one here that I just can't seem to figure out.

My Access front-end project runs on an SQL 2005 express backend.

I have been using subforms for donkeys years and it's the only reason why I haven't migrated the application to a VB/VS front end.

However, since upgrading to Access 2010 I cannot get subforms to work.  Instead, when I try to add a row, I get the following error (The data was added to the database but the data won't be displayed in the form because it doesn't satisfy the criteria in the underlying record source.):

[image]

The master and child forms are linked on poid and PONo.

I have created forms from scratch with all defaults, but still the issue remains.

My SQL tables are

PURCHASE: 
- -
poid, int, PK, Identity, seed 1, inc 1
supplierID, int
orderdate, DateTime
deliverydate, datetime
ordersent, bit
ordercomplete, bit
initials, nvarchar
supplierinvoiceno, nvarchar
branchid, int
bookedin, bit
deliverycharge, money

[STOCK - Detail]:
- -
stockid, int, PK, Identity, Seed 1, inc 1
CodeID, int
service, bit
costprice, money
PONo, int
Instock, bit
SerialNo, char
StockTake, bit
Branch, Char
ProductID, int

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Abe

Comment: Perhaps that bit data type? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753862/run-time-error-3197-ms-access-2010-and-sql-server-2008r2

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, what data type would you suggest instead?

Comment: As it says in the link, smallint seems to work.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.  I spent the weekend updating all the bit fields and I still have the same issue.  Grrrrrrr!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  Access 2010 does not support multiple tables with identical column names unless it is in a stored procedure / query on the SQL server.

I've been trying to come away from stored procs & queries, but A2010 will not, under any combination work with hard coded SQL as the record source.

Once I created a query and selected it as the record source the subforms worked perfectly as expected.

Also I had to alias any fields that have the same name in both tables EVEN if not selected in the query.  And yes, the Alias only worked in the query too!

I love Microsoft! ;-)